# ASP.NET Core is not responding to all Request Http at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm new to asynchronous programming, I made a very simple example where each Request will perform a **select sleep (5)**. This works great when I make a Request only, the result is returned in 5 seconds as expected. But when I execute 100 Request at the same time, it does not work as expected. ASP.NET Core blocks the application and returns the response one after the other, and does not execute all Request at the same time.

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("test1")]
    public async Task<string> test1()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection MySQLCon = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;user id=user1;password=123456"))
        {
            await MySQLCon.OpenAsync();
            using (MySqlCommand MySQLCom = new MySqlCommand("Select sleep(5)", MySQLCon))
            {
                using (var read = await MySQLCom.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {

                }
            }
        }
        return "ok";
    }
    [HttpGet("test2")]
    public async Task<string> test2()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Is this right ? Asynchronous programming should not be the opposite of this, and be able to handle multiple requests at the same time without blocking the application.

I am making requests from an html page using JavaScript asynchronously.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>    
</head>
<body style="margin: 0">
    <button onclick="execultar(1);">test1 (MySQL)</button>
    <button onclick="execultar(2);">test2 (Delay)</button>
    <br />
    <textarea id="log1" style="height: 80vh; width: 700px"></textarea>
    <script>
        function execultar(id_test) {
            var log1 = document.getElementById('log1');
            log1.value = '';
            var count = 0;
            function test1() {
                var start = new Date();
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
                        var end = new Date();
                        var duration = end - start;
                        count++;
                        log1.value +=
                            'test' + id_test.toString() + ' ' + 
                            xhr.responseText +
                            '\tcount:' + count.toString() + ' ' +
                            '\tstart:' + start.toLocaleTimeString() +
                            '\tend:' + end.toLocaleTimeString() +
                            '\tduration:' + duration + 'ms\r\n';
                    }
                }
                xhr.open('GET', '/api/values/test' + id_test.toString(), true);
                xhr.send(null);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                test1();
            }
        }        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The purpose of the code is to simulate situations where SQL queries are taking 5 seconds. This is my big problem, when ASP.NET Core executes several long SQL queries at the same time, the application is blocked even with async. I used Select sleep (5) just to simulate a lengthy query.

On test1 it lasts a long time longer than 5 seconds on most requests.
[image]

On test2 the time is 5 seconds for all requests as expected.
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the expected and actual output off your n=100 test ;-)

Comment: Anyhow, try to decrease the count to 5 or so... depending on your setup, server, host application, settings etc; it is possible that only a couple of simultaneous request are allowed and the others are queued.

Comment: And how does `test2` behave?

Comment: It doesn't look like an asp.net issue. Its probably related to javascript. Javascript in a browser is single threaded.

Comment: @Stefan I put image of the tests. In the case of test2. Behaves exactly as expected, all tests take 5 seconds.

Comment: @zetawars Not a browser problem with single thread, I'm using Chrome, and in the case of test2 it executes all requests at the same time, taking only the 5 seconds expected.

Comment: You're opening a new database connection for every request, which can be time consuming. The amount of time is not going to be entirely predictable. Not sure if that's the root cause, but it can certainly be a problem.

Comment: @MattU I understand that opening multiple connections can be a problem, but that's not the case, because when I perform the same test with ***select current_timestamp*** I don't have any problems since a SQL command that executes fast.

Comment: So, if `test2` is working as expected; the bottle neck is not in the framework. Its in the code of `test1`, can still be a lot of things; additional middleware,  sql connecion pool, network latency or even the MySql implementation. But its definitely not in the framework.

Comment: Do note that in your test run: a lot of them are actually pretty close together; this means that they *are* being runned in parallel.

Comment: @Stefan I think I must be doing something wrong within ASP.NET, I will say why. If I put slow SQL command instead, put HttpClient with slow GET. The application will also crash.
I did a test putting ThreadPool.SetMinThreads (120, 120); in Program Main and got the expected result. But I note in the task manager that there are several Threads, which I don't think is the purpose of ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Hmm... I am not convinced you're doing something wrong relating to asp.net core. It seem more about the usage of the connections (http and mysql) but I cannot be sure. Instead of `select sleep(5);` could you try `do sleep(5);` , just to rule out some nasty locking.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was extremely simple, but I was disappointed with Oracle's MySql.Data library. Because it appears that this library does not use truly asynchronous functions, which causes the ASP.NET Core application to block completely when SQL queries take a long time. The solution was to change the library to [mysqlconnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) and nothing more, no line of my test code has been changed. And now the application works exactly as expected. Even though I perform 100 Requests at the same time, they all end in 5 seconds as expected.

This link https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111 made me think that something was wrong with the Oracle MySql.Data library, after reading I tried with the other library for my happiness.

Comment: The poorly named mysqlconnector is also much faster and supports more features than the Oracle Mysql DB Connector in .net.